# Does Marvel have full filming rights for all characters in Avengers Multiverse?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, x-men-cinematic-universe, copyright, avengers-age-of-ultron

In upcoming Marvel film [Avengers: Age of Ultron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Avengers:_Age_of_Ultron), they are using Quicksilver and Scarlet Witch, characters which are Mutants (X-Men). So has Fox agreed for the characters to be used or Marvel and Fox both own the rights for these X-Men characters?

Comment: I think its they're allowed to use them, but not allowed to mention their true origins (magneto's children).  So they will just appear as more supes.

Comment: X-Men are owned by Marvel, right? Shouldn't be an issue, IMHO.

Comment: @Paulster2 Nopes....Fox has the rights of X-Men movies.

Comment: @TylerShads Quicksilver is also coming in Days of future past too.

Comment: @AnkitSharma ... Good point.

Comment: [This infographic](http://imgur.com/DnXShSd) does a good job illustrating what movie studios own the rights to which characters.

Comment: @Wrathchild good catch.

Comment: Here is my answer, "MULTIVERSE"

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Quicksilver and Scarlet Witch are a special exception to the licensing of the Mutant portion of the Marvel universe to Fox.  Due to them being mutants, but also being important Avengers, both companies retain partial rights to the characters.  Fox can use them as mutants and children of Magneto.  Marvel can use them as Avengers, but they can't mention they're mutants or mention Magneto.

Kevin Feige [said](http://www.superherohype.com/features/articles/170425-exclusive-interview-with-marvel-studios-prez-kevin-feige):

> **Characters like the Scarlet Witch and Quicksilver, are they part of Fox's deal or are they characters you could use?**
>
> Feige: We both have them. There's a specific arrangement with those two characters that would allow us to use them with "Avengers," but not discuss or reference their mutant or Magneto-related lineage. They can use them as mutants and as Magneto's relatives, but cannot have anything to do with "The Avengers."

Comment: *"Fox can use them as mutants and children of Magneto. Marvel can use them as Avengers, but they can't mention they're mutants or mention Magneto."* - What the? Meh, screw those bureaucrats.

Comment: Which is silly as surely mentioning them would help stir up interest in the X-Men films... like all the cameos in the early Avenger films. Why would Fox be against it?

Comment: @Liath The question is more, why would Marvel promote a competitor's movies?

Answer (score 6):

Legally, 20th Century Fox may [object](http://screenrant.com/marvel-comics-movies-characters-carl-6766/) to the use of characters it is producing. So Marvel and Fox may both end up in [suing soup](http://www.comicbookmovie.com/fansites/GraphicCity/news/?a=80174) due to some characters *if* one of them decides to sue the other. Though my opinion would be that both firms lawyers and management would negotiate the films and scripts to get a way out of this. Its just power play to get leverage over the other studio. You can read up more on [Marvel Studios deals with other studios](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marvel_Studios) to get a good picture about how much of Marvel characters are actually licensed outside itself.

Comment: Then its seems Fox is poking marvel intentionally by making quicksilver's screen presence before them.

Comment: I think Marvel first announced Quicksilver and Fox rushed to include him in the script.

Comment: I read somewhere that quicksilver was not in the draft of X-Men earlier.

Answer (score -2):

No, because Scarlet Witch and quicksilver are owned by fox. They made a deal with marvel to use them as long as they don't mention mutants or X-Men and vice versa. Same with spiderman and Sony

Comment: Do you have any sources to back this up?

Comment: https://www.usatoday.com/story/money/2017/11/06/disney-has-been-talks-buy-parts-21st-century-fox-reports-say/836737001/