# Why Disney/Marvel doesn't have rights for Badoon?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, guardians-of-the-galaxy, copyright, 20th-century-fox

[Badoon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Badoon)'s story got stripped away from Guardians of the Galaxy film (2014) and [Wikipedia say’s](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Badoon#Film) Badoon film rights belonged to 20th Century Fox. But how, as per my knowledge Kree more belongs to Fantastic four but it still appeared in Disney properties, similarly in [Quicksilver's case](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/13512/does-marvel-have-full-filming-rights-for-all-characters-in-avengers-multiverse). But why only fox have Badoon’s rights?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To know exactly why, one would have to have access to the contracts. 
*(e.g. even though the [**Kree**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kree) first appeared in a [**Fantastic Four** comic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kree#Publication_history) Marvel was able to use them for [**Guardians of The Galaxy**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2015381/))*

---

But the reason why Marvel doesn't own the film rights to some of their properties goes back to the 90s.

- **In 1996 Marvel [filed for bankruptcy](http://de.eonline.com/news/33907/marvel-files-for-bankruptcy).**
- In 1999 [Peter Cuneo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_Cuneo) became CEO.

  > *"**Coming out of bankruptcy, Marvel was burdened with $250 million in high-yield debt**... We adopted a licensing model for all forms of media, such as movies and television shows, and for consumer products such as clothing and school supplies....*
  >
  > ***Film is unparalleled in its ability to generate worldwide excitement for a fantasy property. Our strategy was to spread out our intellectual property among a variety of Hollywood studios, so that we could attract the most enthusiastic partners for each character.*** One or two film studios could never produce all the films we wanted, and we didn’t like the idea of being tied down to any single partner for all our films.
  >
  > [[Source](http://www.forbes.com/2010/02/01/peter-cuneo-marvel-leadership-managing-turnaround.html)]

[According](http://www.heyuguys.com/the-avengers-european-premiere-interview-producer-kevin-feige-gives-marvel-studios-updates/) to **Kevin Feige** (current president of 'Marvel Studios'):

> ***"...the contracts are very specific... it's a little complicated..."***

He also mentions that [**Scarlet Witch**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scarlet_Witch)/[Quicksilver](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksilver_(comics)) can be used by Marvel *and* FOX (i.e. they have shared rights).

---

In [this interview](http://www.craveonline.com/film/interviews/736791-guardians-galaxy-kevin-feige-marvels-cosmic-universe) Feige says about the [**Skrulls**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skrull):

> *"I think [the rights] are shared. I think they are non-exclusive... **I think [FOX] has [Super-Skrull](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super-Skrull)**, I think it gets pretty detailed and pretty specific who has what.*

And director **[James Gunn](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0348181/)** confirms [here](http://io9.com/why-we-may-never-meet-the-skrulls-in-the-marvel-films-1527485765):

> *"Marvel only partially owns Skrulls, and also **for the record, we don't own the Badoon** either..."*

Comment: 'It's a little complicated' because e.g. even though Scarlet Witch and Quicksilver are Magneto's children, they also, at one point, join the Avengers.

Comment: Ohh...so there is a chance for kree-skrull war.It may be little far fetched but i am still gona wait for something more. Anyways +1.

Comment: __Trivia:__ The film rights to the _Fantastic Four_ were actually [sold in 1986](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Fantastic_Four_(film)#Production), and to keep the rights the production company made a low-budget movie in 1992/1993 which was [never officially released](http://www.joblo.com/movie-news/where-on-the-shelf-isthe-fantastic-four#!bPLLO6). - One can read more about it [here](http://www.teako170.com/ffmovie.html)