# Isn't the Quicksilver from Avengers 2 the same as the Quicksilver from X-Men: Days of Future Past?

Tags: character, marvel-cinematic-universe, x-men-cinematic-universe, avengers-age-of-ultron, x-men-days-of-future-past

According to the X-Men series he is a mutant. But in the Avengers 2 he is depicted as having received his powers through a Hydra experiment.

There are talks in the X-Men about how he is the son of Magneto, but in Avengers he is an orphan whose parents were killed by Stark missiles.

Comment: They have the same names and general abilities but they are **not** mutants, they were *created* in Avengers.

Comment: @Catija The one in Xmen is a mutant.

Comment: Sorry, I meant *they* as in he and Scarlet Witch... because what's true for one is true for both. They are not mutants in Avengers.

Comment: Related (if not even duplicate): http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/13512/49.

Comment: Similar question [Does Marvel have full filming rights for all characters in Avengers Multiverse?](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/13512/does-marvel-have-full-filming-rights-for-all-characters-in-avengers-multiverse/13618#13618)

Comment: here is my answer in one word , it is a "MULTIVERSE" :)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

No, they are completely different characters.

As discussed in this [Sci-Fi & Fantasy question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/52589/is-quicksilver-in-the-x-men-movies-the-same-as-in-avengers-age-of-ultron) and this [Movies & TV question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/13512/49), Scarlet Witch and Quicksilver are rare exceptions to the general licensing deal that Marvel made with Fox. Part of that deal is that Fox has the exclusive rights to make movies about any of the "mutants" in the Marvel Universe: the X-Men, the Brotherhood of Evil Mutants, and all the related characters.

However, Scarlet Witch and Quicksilver are odd, in that they are *also* key members of The Avengers, which Marvel retained the rights to make movies about.

So, those two characters are legally allowed to be in both Marvel and Fox movies, as long as:

- Fox never uses the term Avengers or mentions any other Avengers characters
- Marvel never uses the terms mutant or X-Men, and in particular, never mentions Magneto.

So, the two movie universes have entirely different characters, with entirely different back stories, that just happen to be based on the same comic-book character.

Comment: That sucks.  I mean, this answer is great but it sucks that the Marvel Universe has to be altered because of licensing rights, which makes the whole MU sort of a cheat now.  They have to avoid characters just because some exec wanted $20B and only got $18B?  Ugh...

Comment: @JohnnyBones Well, on the other hand you get not even one, no, two new different backgrounds and stories for your favourite characters, and even backgrounds you didn't know before from the comics and they can make up completely new origin stories disconnected from their various comic incarnations. Just take it as a crisitunity! ;-)

Comment: Us old folks, we can't even remember what brand of tuna we bought the last time we were at the store.  Now I gotta remember different back stories for the same character, and which studio the movie is coming from?  Forget it, I'll skip the movie and go to Bingo instead.  I have to be in bed by 7PM anyway, otherwise my bunions start hurting.

Comment: @JohnnyBones - It also means they avoid all the crossover and what-else-is-going-on issues that the comic book universes have.  If the Avengers are dealing with world-destroying threats, but the X-Men don't even notice (or vice-versa), that's weird.  And if two X-men movies take place a year apart, but the Avengers ones released interleaved with them have a shorter gap, you get weird timing issues.  Personally, I prefer the one-universe-per-superteam model.

Comment: @JohnnyBones Marvel already has dozens of universes, including at least two extremely long-running comics (the mainstream -616 and the Ultimate one). The MCU and Fox Universe are just two more of them, neither of which actually matches the original -616 precisely.

Comment: @JohnnyBones: Or just do what Batman fans do: just don't care and enjoy the ride. If you completely ignore Batman movies and looks at just the comics, Batman itself has so many universes that most (save from a few dedicated souls, and wikipedia) fans have lost track. There's a Batman who's a Green Lantern, a Vampire Batman, several different Bruce Waynes who died and had others take over as Batman.. and that's just the canon.

Comment: Doesn't this answer completely invalidate [Walt Hickey's analysis](http://fivethirtyeight.com/datalab/which-characters-deserve-to-join-the-avengers-in-the-next-movie/) at FiveThirtyEight? In other words, if Avengers(Comic) Membership makes Quicksliver available, it would also make available Wolverine, The Thing, Mr. Fantastic, Beast, The Invisible Woman, and Storm.

Comment: This answer is based on the facts as they have been revealed to us by Marvel executives. These two characters are available because Fox agreed to let them be, end of story. Why Marvel choose to fight for these two, according to Feige, is because they were well known as Avengers than the other mutants, but the idea that Fox would pay for the X-men and not get exclusive rights to Wolverine is almost silly.

Comment: @JohnnyBones: “Now I gotta remember different back stories for the same character?” You don’t read a lot of comic books, do you.

Comment: @JohnnyBones- you really dont have to bother that much because one of the 2 is dead now.. :P

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - Honestly, I never got into comics.  And I'm sure I'm not the only one who can say that I really love the movies and I grew up watching Superfriends on Saturday mornings and The Incredible Hulk starring Lou Ferrigno, etc, etc...  So, this "alternate version of the same character" thing is difficult for me and my ilk to handle; I just want *one* Quicksilver and it's silly to have multiple back stories.  It's like when a series reboots and the back story is different.  In my perfect little OCD world, I want one history.

Comment: @JohnnyBones: so Avengers 1 isn’t ruined by the existence of Lou Ferrigno’s Hulk?

Comment: Ferrigno's Hulk was in the 70's.  I'm OK with a reboot of the MU.  I'm not OK with a reboot of MU every 2 years, where every prior movie becomes moot because the history and relationships change.  It's just stupid.  Just show me your universe and let me live in it.  These comics have been around for 50 years.  They've had enough time to sort out all the storylines.  Is that unreasonable to ask?